# Program to trigger "Build Now" on jenkins and display console output

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jenkins

I have an application that takes the changes and pushes on git. Now i want to create a deploy button on my application, clicking on which, will automatically trigger "Build Now" on Jenkins and display the console output on my application. (I am already storing the userid and password for jenkins within my application.) This will enable me to do everything within my application, from creating the changes, pushing to git and finally deploying it on jenkins and seeing the console output without actually going to jenkins and doing it manually.
More info:My application is built in Spring boot and thymeleaf as frontend.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jenkins CLI](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/)

> The command line interface can be accessed over SSH or with the Jenkins CLI client, a .jar file distributed with Jenkins.

with **build** command

> One of the most common and useful CLI commands is build, which allows the user to trigger any job or Pipeline for which they have permission.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins also has a REST api that you can use, use POsT to trigger and GET for the reults

https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=753720#content/view/753720